# What markup is allowed in the description of a facebook feed post?

Tags: facebook

Upon playing with it, it appears that the description for a facebook feed post made by an application can have some html in it. All I've found that works is <b> and <i> but even <br> doesn't work. What sort of formatting is allowed? Or at the very least how can i start a new line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is it: http://www.facebook.com/notes_cheatsheet.php

Comment: This isn't correct, that is just the cheat sheet for markup for "notes".  For example, you can add user <center> tag in feed post description.  However, I'm not sure where the full list is, there doesn't appear to be any documentation anywhere.

Comment: [Broken link.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/700/can-we-get-rid-of-the-threshold-of-15-chars-for-comments)

Answer (score 2):

For the record, `<i>`, `<b>`, `<small>` and `<center>` at least work. They only want you to use inline markup, but as a hack you can put `<center></center>` to make line breaks.